# Third Isomorphism Theorem for Rings confusions

Tags: ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I am having some confusion about the Third Isomorphism Theorem for Rings that I hope could be clarified.

Take $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$.  I want to mod out by $(x^2 + 1, y^2 + y + 7)$.  Therefore, I use the third isomorphism theorem to say that doing so is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}[x,y] / (x^2 +1) / (x^2 + 1, y^3 + y) / (x^2 + 1)$.

I know that from the proof of the third isomorphism theorem it must be the case that $(x^2 + 1, y^2 + y + 7) / (x^2 + 1)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x,y] / (x^2 + 1)$.  But here is my confusion:

1) is there a way to say explicitly what $(x^2 + 1, y^2 + y + 7) / (x^2 + 1)$ is (besides just saying that it is a set of cosets)?

2) $\mathbb{R[x,y]} / (x^2 + 1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$ under the isomorphism derived as a result of the map from $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ to $\mathbb{C}[t]$ $x \mapsto i$, $y\mapsto t$ (first isomorphism theorem). 
Therefore, the ideal $(x^2 + 1, y^2 + y + 7) / (x^2 + 1)$ will be mapped (under the inverse of the above isomorphism) to an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[t]$.  In my notes, I have (with no explanation) that this ideal is $(t^2 + t + 7)$.  Could someone explain why this is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use Mathjax, it's very annoying to read textual mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an isomorphism, you can go in both directions, so just apply the isomorphism you gave:

$$(x^2 + 1, y^2 + y + 7) / (x^2 + 1) \mapsto (i^2 + 1, t^2 + t + 7) = (0, t^2 + t + 7) = ( t^2 + t + 7).$$

Or just notice that

$$ (x^2 + 1, y^2 + y + 7) / (x^2 + 1) = (y^2 + y + 7) / (x^2 + 1).$$

Comment: See above---Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) One way to visualize this quotient would be by viewing it as the first ideal "minus" the other. We have a homomorphism from $(x^2+1,y^2+y+7)$ to $(x^2+1,y^2+y+7)/(x^2+1)$ which sends elements from $(x^2+1)$ to $0$ , so that, in one sense, we "eliminated" the second ideal from the other.

2) Indeed, if we map $x$ to $i$ and $y$ to $t$, $(x^2+1,y^2+y+7)\mapsto (i^2+1,t^2+t+7)=(0,t^2+t+7)=(t^2+t+7)$ and $(x^2+1)\mapsto (i^2+1)=0$. As well, $(t^2+t+7)/{0}=(t^2+t+7)$, which is the result you wanted.

Comment: Thanks 57Jimmy and TPace for the explanation.  I still have two mild points of confusion.  First, the isomorphism is not x -> i, y -> t; it is induced by that map.  It is an isomorphism on equivalence classes.  However, (please correct me if I am wrong), it is still the same map x -> i y -> t but on the equivalence class of x and the equivalence class of y, correct?

Second: How do you know for sure that (x^2 + 1,y^2 + y + 7) -> (i^2 + 1,t^2 + t +7) and why are you able to break it across the mod?  Because it is an isomorphism?  If it were not an isomorphism would it fail?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: If it were not an iso it would not be true?

Comment: On the second question: as every element of our ideal may be represented by an expression envolving $x^2+1$ or $y^2+y+7$ and these elements are mapped to, respectively, $0$ and $t^2+t+7$, therefore every element of the image of our ideal may be represented as an expression envolving these two elements. Note that this has only to do with the fact that our mapping is a homomorphism. About the use of the mod: if f is a homomorphism, f(G/N)={f(Ne),f(Na),...}={f(N)f(e),f(N)f(a),...}=f(G)/f(N). Therefore, the unique condition we need is the homomorphism one.

Comment: perfectly explained!

Comment: Thanks! If you've more questions, feel free to ask them :)